# Cannot pass values to an AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using an `AsyncTask` in an activity.

here is my code

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


 EditText editUserNameLogin;
 EditText editPassLogin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    //ButterKnife.bind(this);

    editUserNameLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_username_login);
    editPassLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password_login);

}

public class AsyncTaskClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    String strUserName = editUserNameLogin.getText().toString();
    String passLogin = editPassLogin.getText().toString();


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, passLogin, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String r) {

    }
}
```

but in `doInBackground` can't get values `passLogin` or `strUserName`
(`Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, passLogin,`) don't show any text)

Comment: You should work with UI in the `onPostExecute`

Comment: you can not write toast inside doInBackground method.If you want your passLogin value then use Log for that to print.

Comment: you can not write UI related code inside doInBackground, LogCat will be more preferable

Comment: how can I get value edittex in oncreate() inside AsyncTask code below I just check value of edittext :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not perform UI operation inside background AsyncTask doInBackground method because AsyncTask not work with current UI thread, its create new thread while you initialize and execute.

Let me explain you in bref.

While activity start its stay with Activity Thread and when you complete activity operation and destroy its completely remove from operation task.
But while you start AsyncTask on Activity its start with individual operation stat that not depends on activity that you start, so if you perform UI operation in doInBackground method and in case Activity destroyed and you working on UI that already destroyed by activity and UI  cannot get reference, its generate an exception. So it's necessary to work with current activity thread not another background thread.

There are many case that you can pass data inside AsyncTask, i'm comfortable with below operation, it can help you also.

```
// Pass data to AsyncTask comma separated values
new MyBackgroundTask().execute("Hello there!","How are you?");

private class MyBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String message1 = strings[0];
        String message2 = strings[1];

        Log.d("_TAG_", "First String: " + message1);
        Log.d("_TAG_", "Second String: " + message2);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
```

For more information read Android Official Documents [AsyncTask Developer Guides](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: how can I get value  edittex in oncreate() inside AsyncTask code below I just check value of edittext  :  String strUserName = editUserNameLogin.getText().toString()

Answer (score 1):

Try and execute `AsyncTaskClass` in `onCreate`

```
new AsyncTaskClass().execute();  //use this method and call this in onCreate
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, inside `onCreate`

```
String response="checking";
new AsyncTaskClass().execute(response);
```

then create inner class AsyncTaskClass,

```
 private class AsyncTaskClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String > {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String respose1 = strings[0];
        return respose1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant show ui operations like toast in doInBackground if you still want to do that then use this code to display toast while in doInBackground

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

and also you need to call yourAsyncTaskObject.execute to start asynctask

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what exactly you want to achieve by such behavior.
But i am pointing out some point here . First of all you can not access any UI element in background thread .

```
 @Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, passLogin, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The above code is not going to work as `doInBackground` runs asynchronously separate  from UI thread.

If you want to show a toast on `AsyncTask` started then do it in `onPreExecute` or after execution do it in `onPostExecute`.

```
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, passLogin, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

**And** as i see you never execute the `AsyncTask` then how are you expecting anything from it. Do call `execute()`.

```
new AsyncTaskClass().execute();
```

For more on `AsyncTask` read [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: I use Toast just check value strUsername but it can't get values

Answer (score 0):

**Try the following:**

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {    
            @Override
            public void run() {
               Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, passLogin, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
            }
    });            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> [**`AsyncTask`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
>   allows you to perform background operations and publish results on the
>   UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

```
new AsyncTaskClass("SEND STRING").execute();
```

You can pass this Your Value this way

```
private class AsyncTaskClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    String strRESPONSE="";

    public MyAsyncTask(String str_GET) {
         this.strRESPONSE=str_GET; // print "SEND STRING"

    }


}
```